# Converting time format in PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently working on converting the time format to the format for ISO8601.

My current timestamp style is 
2014/9/29 23:59:59'

and I want this to be changed as
2014-09-29T23:59:59

can anyone tell me how I would do this in either JavaScript or PHP?

For PHP I was going to use date function but did not work out quite well.

Comment: what is 'T' means in '2014-09-29T23:59:59' ?

Comment: @iatboy The 'T' only indicates the beginning of the `Time` element

Comment: In javascript, just rearrange the parts.